# Curbed tyre is it safe to drive

Tags: tires, safety, sidewall-damage

[image]

I think I may already know the answer to my question, just want some second opinions. 
I curved my tyre yesterday taking a chunk of rubber out of it. Does it need replacing or is it safe to drive for a short period of time? [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mike. It shouldn't be an issue as long as you're not driving crazy, I would also say watch out for large potholes as the damage may have weakened the sidewall. *PERSONALLY* I've had very similar damage in appearance and in order to cheaply ease my mind got some "goop". This product is not made to or recommended for the repair of tires. However it's incredibly durable, completely water resistant, and sets in about 45minutes. If done correctly this should alleviate the potential "pinching" Mike mentioned. *This is all just an opinion, use at your own risk.*

Answer (score 0):

A picture showing the end of that damage so we can see the root would help.

But it looks as if the damage has only removed the protector portion of the tire. The danger is that this may cause the tire wall to de-laminate in that area due to pinching.

Without further pictures, IMO it should be ok to continue driving on it, but inspect it OFTEN just to make sure. If this is a performance car used at high speed most of the time then get it replaced - if is a town run-about doing slow speeds then inspect it often.

Your safety and your passengers are most important - if you are worried then get it changed or, at least, put it on the rear.

Comment: Hi Solar Mike, thanks for your answer! Please see above for another attached picture of the end of the damage. Thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Answer still stands.

Comment: A pleasure, stay safe.